# How would you take advantage of the knowing the zeros in T, a tridiagonal matrix, in a code for Gaussian elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

When $T$ is tridiagonal, its $L$ and $U$ factor have only two nonzero diagonals. How would you take advantage of the knowing the zeros in $T$, in a code for Gaussian elimination? Find $L$ and $U$.

$$T=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$

Finding $L$ and $U$:

$${ E }_{ 21 }T=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$

$${ E }_{ 32 }({ E }_{ 21 }T)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$

$${ E }_{ 43 }({ E }_{ 32 }{ E }_{ 21 }T)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=U$$

$L={ E }_{ 21 }^{ -1 }{ E }_{ 32 }^{ -1 }{ E }_{ 43 }^{ -1 }$, so we get:

$${ E }_{ 32 }^{ -1 }{ E }_{ 43 }^{ -1 }=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$${ E }_{ 21 }^{ -1 }{ E }_{ 32 }^{ -1 }{ E }_{ 43 }^{ -1 }=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=L$$

I found $L$ and $U$, but I am unsure of how knowing the zeros in $T$ would come in use when attempting to write more efficient code for elimination.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [Thomas algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm).